# Use Firebase.com authenication without forcing the user to create an account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a small App to allow the user to store To-Do items. I am using Firebase ass my backend.
For the first iteration I don't want the user to have to sign-up, but still only see it's own data. My first thought was just to use the anonymous authentication, store the UID an reuse it everytime the app is started. This is not possible since the session is gonna time out at some point and the user would get a new UID the next time.
I of course want to make sure that a user can only see it's own items using the Firebase Security & Rules.

The idea would be to save the items like this: **app.firebase.com/user/123456/todo-item**

123456 beeing the unique ID of the user.
Can I create a unique identifier myself and still use the Firebase Security & Rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**You would have to run your own custom authentication solution.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html)

When the Activity loads, you'll have to make a request to your server. Then on the server you can create tokens for a user when they load the page:

```
// These payload properties are accessible 
// by Security Rules which is awesome
Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
payload.put("uid", "uniqueId1");
payload.put("some", "arbitrary");
payload.put("data", "here");

TokenGenerator tokenGenerator = new TokenGenerator("<YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>");
String token = tokenGenerator.createToken(payload);
```

There's more packages than just Java, so read the docs.

Then when you deliver the token back to the user, you would need to store the token locally.

Once the token is stored, you can retrieve it and authenticate.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");
ref.authWithCustomToken(AUTH_TOKEN, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError error) {
        System.err.println("Login Failed! " + error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
        // authenticated
    }
});
```

You probably aren't thrilled about having to run a server, but take a look at using Google AppEngine with the Firebase JVM client. It's pretty easy and handles the server maintenance for you.

**[This tutorial by a former Google Cloud tools member, and current Firebase team member is a great place to start.](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio)**

Comment: Any chance to generate the token without the need run an additional server?

Comment: It's technically possible to run all that code on the client. However you'll expose your key to the world and then your Firebase database is no longer secure. So no, you need a server. But like I said, the AppEngine setup is easy and low-maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I'll try this out.